# How to load a saved DNN estimator model for predicting?

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, restore, tensorflow-estimator

I have a saved DNN estimator model. How can I restore the model for prediction?
I saved my model using:

```
#Create the input function
input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_train, y=y_train, batch_size=100, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)

#Create the model
model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feat_cols, hidden_units=[10, 10], n_classes=2, model_dir=model_path)
```

So, inside the model_path directory, I have:

> - checkpoint
> - event.out.tf...
> - graph.pbtxt
> - model.ckpt-1...
> - model.ckpt-1...
> - model.ckpt-1...
> - model.ckpt-5000...
> - model.ckpt-5000...
> - model.ckpt-5000...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [predictor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/32ffc5a81eee8c39bbe71536212a773b1ffd4eb2/tensorflow/contrib/predictor/saved_model_predictor.py#L114) as follow.

```py
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor

my_predict = predictor.from_saved_model(model_path)
prediction = my_predict({"x": [your_testing_data]})
```

Hope this helps!